# jQuery object not draggable when recreated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Please visit http://classrecon.com/invest/mockup.html for the example of my problem. To recreate the problem:

1. Drag `PULM` into the "Has these targets..." field and drop.
2. Delete the tag by hitting the X to the right of the tag.
3. PROBLEM: Notice that when you try to drag `<delete element's text>` the element won't drag.

How can I make the new tag draggable? And how can I transfer the deleted tag's text to the new tag?

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $(".drag-key").draggable();
    $(".tag-collection").droppable({
        over: function(event, ui){
            $(this).css("background-color","rgba(0,191,255,.3)");
        },
        out: function(event, ui){
            $(this).css("background-color","white");
        },
        drop: function(event, ui){
            $("<div class='key'></div>").text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this ).append(" <span class='remove'>✘</span>");
            ui.draggable.remove();
        }
    });

    // I THINK THE PROBLEM IS HERE
    $(document).on('click', 'span.remove', function() {
        $(".key-rep").append("<div class=\"drag-key key\">&lt;removed element's text&gt;</div>");
        $(this).closest('.key').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to run the line  `$(".drag-key").draggable();` again at the end of `$(document).on('click', 'span.remove', function() {`

It should look like this

```
$(document).on('click', 'span.remove', function() {
        $(".key-rep").append("<div class=\"drag-key key\">&lt;removed element's text&gt;</div>");
        $(this).closest('.key').hide();
        $(".drag-key").draggable();
    });
```

Here is a JSFiddle with the suggested fix

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FYeBC/)

Answer (score 0):

When you `.append()` the markup for a new drag-key, it is just that.. a brand new element. It was not present at the time you created the selected `$(".drag-key")`, and made all elements matching that selector draggable. It doesn't contain the events or class associated with JQuery draggables. If you want to make your new drag-key draggable, you'll have to `.draggable()` the newly created element just like you did the original element(s).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `delegate()` method to make divs draggable when appends to key-rep.